# How can we Fetch Jira card color to show it on Jira Dashboard

Tags: jql

i have Set color of the card on Jira board

[screenshot of  board configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alpcx.png)

and this is how the issues appears on the Kanban Board view
[screenshot of card view on board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHckD.png)

am trying to fetch the color of the card set by the query to show on Jira Dashboard
[screenshot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNM6E.png)

I am not sure if it is possible to get the color value or use any custom query on the dashboard.

Comment: The *cards* have a color on your board, not the issues itself. On your dashboard you have a display of the issues which is entirely unrelated to any cards or board filters and their logic. If I create another dashboard with entirely different colors what should happen to your dashboard!?